# How to run C project in Eclipse IDE?

Tags: eclipse, c

I downloaded Eclipse IDE for from [here](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-cc-developers-includes-incubating-components/indigosr2) and I create a sample project from [here](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-cc-developers-includes-incubating-components/indigosr2) I followed steps as above link.But in code displays error in "#include" header file.how do I resolve this issue.Please help me.Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the error? Is it occurring **in** the header file itself? Or **at** the `#include` statement? What are you trying to include, a standard library or a custom header file?

Comment: Standard lib stdio.h i can't run simple program mr.kyle

Answer (score 1):

Do you have `MinGW` installed? [MinGW is a GCC compiler for Windows](http://www.mingw.org/), you need it in order to compile projects on Windows.

Comment: in eclipse IDE compiler not attached ah?sorry if i ask silly

Comment: @Segfault is right. You need a toolchain. Sometimes it's included, sometimes it's not. Depends on how and where you download it. Here is the information you need: http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fcdt_c_before_you_begin.htm

Comment: Its says "unresolved Inclusion" mesage